# Changing visibility of menu items in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I'm trying to hide some menu items when a fragment is changed, but seems that this is not working. Here is what im doing:
Defining the menu and menu items:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_sharecall, menu);

        actionMenu = menu;
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_searchmenuitem);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_menushare);
        // item.setVisible(false);
        // searchItem.setVisible(false);

        topSearch = searchItem;
        topShare = item;
        final MRShareActionProvider actionProvider = new MRShareActionProvider(
                this);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, actionProvider);
        actionProvider
                .setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
        actionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);
        actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
        return true;

    }
```

changing the fragment and changing the visibility:

```
  //changing visibility    
    topSearch.setVisible(false);
    frag = new SyncFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, frag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

and this is my SyncFragment:

```
public class SyncFragment extends MRBaseACBFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sync, null);
    }


}
```

but after the fragment is changed, i can still see the menu item. Can someone help me with a solution on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it does not work, but try to change the visibility directly in the `onCreateOptionMenu`.

If it works, then when you want to hide it call `invalidateOptionsMenu` (or `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` for actionbar compat), it will force the `onCreateOptionMenu` to be called again and you can update the menu if the fragment is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment add below code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }



 @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow).setVisible(false);
    }
```