# Unable to hide activity's options menu on some fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, show-hide, android-optionsmenu

I am using options menu in an activity, in that I have inflated menu and onItemSelected for the menu item is done. And in fragment I am hiding the menu items which are not required to show on the fragment.

This is done well, I can see the desired menu items on the fragments. But on some fragments I dont want to show any menu item. So for this I tried to clear the menu, also I tried to setVisible false to all the items, also tried to setHasOptionsMenu(false); , But none is working. I can see all three menu items on that fragment.

Also I tried this answer: Hide/Show Action Bar Option Menu Item for different fragments

From Search merchants fragment in onPreparedOptionsMenu I did menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.main_menu_group, false);

Still not working.

Menu

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_group">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="customer"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="customer"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_create"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="customer"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_save"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Home activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    //     menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_customer, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_create:

            String favMerchantId = pref.getString("favMerchantId","");
            String favKiranaName = pref.getString("favKiranaName","");

            if(pref.getString("favMerchantId","").equals("null") && pref.getString("favKiranaName","").equals("null")){

                CommonUtils.showAlert(HomeActivity.this,"There is no merchant yet.Please search for merchant.","No Merchant");

            }

            else {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                AddOrderFragment fragment1 = new AddOrderFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("kiranaName", favKiranaName);
                bundle.putString("merchant_id", String.valueOf(favMerchantId));
                bundle.putBoolean("ordersFrag", true);
                fragment1.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment1, "RETRIEVE_ADDORDER_FRAGMENT").addToBackStack("B").commit();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.action_edit:

            if (CommonUtils.isConnectedToInternet(HomeActivity.this)) {

                if(AddOrderFragment.mOrderItemsList.isEmpty())
                {
                    CommonUtils.showAlert(HomeActivity.this,getResources().getString(R.string.listAlert),"List");
                    // showAlert(getString(R.string.listAlert));
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("itemList", String.valueOf(AddOrderFragment.mOrderItemsList.size()));

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String toServer = gson.toJson(
                            Collections.singletonMap("items", AddOrderFragment.mOrderItemsList)
                    );

                    String date_time = String.valueOf(CommonUtils.getCurrentDateTime());

                    new AddOrderAsyncTask(HomeActivity.this,AddOrderFragment.ordersFrag).execute(toServer,pref.getString("api_key",""), pref.getString("sessionUserId",""), AddOrderFragment.mMerchantId,date_time);
                }

            }
            else {
                // showAlert(getString(R.string.check_network));
                CommonUtils.showAlert(HomeActivity.this,getResources().getString(R.string.check_network),"Check network");
            }

            break;
        case R.id.action_search:
            // go to search fragment


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = HomeActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            SearchMerchantFragment fragment1 = new SearchMerchantFragment();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment1).addToBackStack("D").commit();
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
order's fragment to hide some menu items :

    @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);


    MenuItem someMenuItem3 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_create);
    someMenuItem3.setVisible(true);
    // This does work
    MenuItem someMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    someMenuItem.setVisible(false);

    MenuItem someMenuItem1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
    someMenuItem1.setVisible(false);
}
```

Search merchant fragment : In this I want to hide the menu, or all the menu items.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

       MenuItem someMenuItem3 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_create);
    someMenuItem3.setVisible(false);
    // This does work
    MenuItem someMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    someMenuItem.setVisible(false);

    MenuItem someMenuItem1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
    someMenuItem1.setVisible(false);

}
```

How can I hide this menu?

Please help.. Thank you..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178663/hide-show-action-bar-option-menu-item-for-different-fragments/32887678#32887678

Comment: You can go through this following stack overflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126336/android-how-to-hide-menu-option-for-current-fragment

Comment: Maybe you can add menu item programmatically

Comment: I tried both links above.

Comment: What do you mean programmatically?@Michal_196

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can try this,

```
@Override 
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
}
```

and

`setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate` of fragment.

Comment: its not working I have tried to clear the menu also setHasOptionsMenu(false);.

Comment: if you are clearing menus you should use setHasOptionsMenu(true); in oncreate

Comment: this clear all of optionMenus. if i want clear activity menus and add fragment menu, what i do?